# How do I rescue a Capybara Error Twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling, capybara

I'm using Capybara to check a page for an element and return it's content.  If the element doesn't exist i'd like to look for a different element's content and return that.  If neither are found i'd like to return an empty string.

The challenge here is that Capybara throws a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error when `#find` fails.

For selecting when the case is "return the element or an empty string" this is easy -- i simply `rescue` and return the empty string like below:

```
def select_post_meta_name(page)
  selector = 'div.post-name'
  page.find(selector).text
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
  Rails.logger.warn('Could not get meta name: ' + e)
  ''
end
```

How would i refactor the code above to handle something like the intent of the following pseudo code?

```
# FAKE EMBARRASSING PSEUDO CODE ....
def select_post_meta_name(page)
  selector = 'div.post-name'
  page.find(selector).text
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
  other_element_selector = 'div.post-title'
  page.find(other_element_selector).text

  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    Rails.logger.warn('Could not find any elements: ' + e)
    ''
end
# /FAKE EMBARRASSING PSEUDO CODE ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this, nesting exceptions works from what I have done. This should work and the second time the exception is thrown then you can say for sure that what you are doing it truly broken.

```
# FAKE EMBARRASSING PSEUDO CODE ....
def select_post_meta_name(page)
  selector = 'div.post-name'
  begin
    page.find(selector).text
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    begin
      other_element_selector = 'div.post-title'
      page.find(other_element_selector).text
    rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
      Rails.logger.warn('Could not find any elements: ' + e)
      ''
    end
  end
end
# /FAKE EMBARRASSING PSEUDO CODE ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *retry* in rescue block or "recursive" call the method again with param.

```
def select_post_meta_name(page, meta_name = 'div.post-name')
  re_try = false
  begin
    page.find(meta_name).text
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    if re_try
      Rails.logger.warn('Could not find any elements: ' + e)
    else
      meta_name = 'div.post-title'
      re_try = true
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method again with a flag saying that you are executing the method for a second time:

```
def select_post_meta_name(page, selector = 'div.post-name', first_call_of_method = true)
  begin
    page.find(selector).text
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    if first_call_of_method
      select_post_meta_name(page, 'div.post-title', false)
    else
      Rails.logger.warn('Could not find any elements: ' + e)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In tis case, you can use just rescue without begin. :)